# HttpResponse Header Information Leakage on Server Error (Verbose Headers)

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-headers, verbose

In the past I have dealt with security issues related to Default Service Banners/Verbose Headers/Information Leakage via HttpResponse Headers.  These issues are quite common, and usually look something like this for an Asp.Net - IIS Server.

Server:  Microsoft-IIS/10.0

X-AspNet-Version:  4.0.30319

X-Powered-By:  ASP.NET

These types of issues are very common, and usually quite trivial to deal with, typically a web.config update or an URLRewrite rule to remove the verbose headers.

However, one issue I stumbled upon lately, is when the Server encounters an error, these headers are not removed.  For example a 404 (not found) error will still have these headers appended on.  In fact most error responses are not able to properly remove the information leakage headers.  I did some searching and found out this issue is not very well documented, in fact it has never come up in one of our Pen-Tests specifically.

I am curious if any other developers have dealt with this issue, specifically information leakage in HttpResponse Headers when the response code is an Error.  If so, how did you fix it.  I am using Microsoft, Asp.Net, IIS technologies, but still curious if other technologies/servers have this issue.

Comment: HTTP Response Header will not really be removed, it is just hidden, but it should not be affected when the server encounters an error(Except maybe in some special cases), which methods have you tried, maybe you can refer to this link: [https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/ba-p/369710](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/ba-p/369710).

Comment: @samwu Thanks Mate, but I have already tried all of those ways, they work fine for 200 response but not for 4xx, etc.  Please, see the last comment on the link you sent me, "it works fine on 200 status code
on 400 error, server header shows "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"
on 404 error, server header still shows "Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
on 200, server header shows "Unknown" as per my value in rewrite module.
my registry entry is DisableServerHeader = 1
why it is not working? I am using windows server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5"

Comment: I think the best case, is to remove the headers at the Load Balancer level, add them to the Load Balancer iRule black-list, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Cody (Security Champion)  response.

reviving an old thread here, but we have had many applications to mitigate this problem for. we've actually done it at **the load balancer level**, so that all responses, error or otherwise, are treated the same

we're doing that with an **iRule for F5** - iRules Home

https://clouddocs.f5.com/api/irules/

the irule has an array of blacklisted header names, and just removes those on every response

if you're trying to accomplish the same thing within AWS or some other managed load balancing mechanism, unfortunately i'm not sure how you would go about doing that